# Custom TableCell Button click to new ViewController in iOS(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have create Custom TableCell for my TableView. In the Custom Cell I have `Button`. So I want to open New ViewController when Button is click.and send Data on it. So How to create Event in Custom TableCell to open new ViewController.

I am create this way Is this right way or not ?

**my CustomCell :**

```
public partial class CaseHistotyTableCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("CaseHistotyTableCell");
        public static readonly UINib Nib;

        static CaseHistotyTableCell()
        {
            Nib = UINib.FromName("CaseHistotyTableCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        }

        protected CaseHistotyTableCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public static CaseHistotyTableCell Create()
        {
            return (CaseHistotyTableCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
        }
        internal void BindData(string hospitalLabel, string addressLabel, string drLabel, string patientLabel)
        {
            this.lbl_hospitalName.Text = hospitalLabel;
            this.lbl_address.Text = addressLabel;
            this.lbl_drName.Text = drLabel;
            this.lbl_patientName.Text = patientLabel;

            this.lbl_address.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.54f);
            this.lbl_patientName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.54f);
            this.lbl_hospitalName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.87f);
            this.lbl_drName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.87f);
            this.btn_createAppointment.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA",1.0f), UIControlState.Normal);
            this.btn_viewDetail.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f), UIControlState.Normal);

            this.btn_viewDetail.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            {

            };


        }



        public override CGRect Frame
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Frame;
            }

            set
            {
                value.Y += 4;
                value.Height -= 2 * 4;
                base.Frame = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**SourceClass :**

```
public class CaseHistorySourceClass : UITableViewSource
    {
        private List<CaseSearchItem> caseSearchItems;
        public CaseSearchItem caseSearchItem;

    public CaseHistorySourceClass(List<CaseSearchItem> caseSearchItems)
    {
        this.caseSearchItems = caseSearchItems;
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        CaseHistoryTableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CaseHistoryTableCell.Key) as CaseHistoryTableCell ?? CaseHistoryTableCell.Create();
        var item = caseSearchItems[indexPath.Row];

        cell.BindData(item.Organization, item.Address, item.Doctor, item.UserName);

        cell.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
        cell.Layer.CornerRadius = 10.0f;
        cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;



        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return caseSearchItems.Count;
    }


}
```

I am new to iOS and Xamarin. Any help be Appreciated.

Comment: For the custom cell u are rendering a `TableCell` right, when click i assume i should call the on `button clicked` method in ur table cell. Try putting a breakpoint and see when click it should call the view thats extends TabbleCell

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
this.btn_viewDetail.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
   {
     TargetController myTarget = new TargetController ();
     myTarget.YourString = "Your value here";
     this.NavigationController.PushViewController(myTarget, true);
   };
```

Comment: I want this on `Button` click not on `RowClick`.

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller, where you defining datasource for your Tableview, add variable for your view controller for example..

```
 public class mytableDataSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        private ViewController owner;
        List<string> tableItems;
        public mytableDataSource(ViewController cntrlr, List<string items)
        {
            tableItems = items;
            owner = cntrlr;

        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("your identifier");
            //cell. BindData(.....
            cell.getDetailButton.Tag = indexPath.Row;
            cell.getDetailButton.TouchUpInside -= handler;
            cell.getDetailButton.TouchUpInside += handler;
             
        }
        void handler(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        { 
            var btn = (Button) sender;
            nint tag = btn.Tag;
            TargetController myTarget = new TargetController();
            myTarget.YourString = list[];
            owner.NavigationController.PushViewController(myTarget, true);
        }
         
    }
```

when assigning datasource to your tableview, pass `this` too as parameter.for example:

```
 tbl.Source = new mytableDataSource(lstService, this);
  tbl.ReloadData();
```

To make cell  button available from in view controller, create Property in cs file.

```
public UIButton getDetailButton
    {
    get
        {
            return btn_viewDetail;
        }
    }
```

Comment: wait i try this and tell you later.

Comment: @Ironman I have update answer to use handler, to avoid getting multiple delegate assign on button when get cell called multiple times.

Comment: I can't access `this.btn_viewDetail.Tag = indexPath.Row;` in `GetCell` method ?

Comment: oops sorry..try cell.btn_viewDetail.Tag = indexPath.Row ;

Comment: and same for  assigning handler, try cell.btn_viewDetail.TouchUpInside -= handler;

Comment: `cell.btn_viewDetail.Tag is inaccessible due to its protection level` but when i set it `public` is also display same error. I have posted my `TableCell` in the question.

Comment: Did you typecast cell ? CaseHistotyTableCell cell1 = (CaseHistotyTableCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("youridentifier"); ? 
 or just have public method in you cell to return button and use that.

Comment: Why You have not defined property for btn_viewDetail in you cell?  you said you did it?  btn_viewDetail definition should be in Designer file, Create property of it in class file.

Comment: @iOS_developer i try your update answer but it not work for me. By the way thnx for time.

Comment: nint tag = btn.Tag;  <- there's no object btn defined... where do you get this reference from?

Comment: @AdamB You can get that from Object Sender. Updated answer accordingly. Please check.

Comment: So simple! Thanks for helping us noobs.